# c2dm can't open keycharmap file

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm, android-2.2-froyo

I have a problem with my c2dm application. When I run the app from eclipse and send a message from my server it arrives on my phone. But if I send another message from my server after this initial message it keeps sending my first message e.g when I launch the app I send a message "Test" then I send Test2 however I never receive test2 instead I receive test. On the second attempt, it says in logcat can't open keycharmap file.

Logcat:

```
03-20 15:44:41.702: D/ATRecorder(5540): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader 

dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@405273d0
03-20 15:44:41.902: D/WindowManagerImpl(5540): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40521618
03-20 15:44:53.374: W/C2DM(5540): Message Receiver called
03-20 15:44:53.374: W/C2DM(5540): Received message
03-20 15:44:53.384: D/C2DM(5540): dmControl: payload = test
03-20 15:44:55.846: D/ATRecorder(5540): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@40531ca8
03-20 15:44:55.856: D/WindowManagerImpl(5540): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052eda0
03-20 15:45:06.566: W/C2DM(5540): Message Receiver called
03-20 15:45:06.566: W/C2DM(5540): Received message
03-20 15:45:06.566: D/C2DM(5540): dmControl: payload = test2
03-20 15:45:12.162: D/ATRecorder(5540): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@405390d8
03-20 15:45:12.162: D/WindowManagerImpl(5540): addView, new view, mViews[2]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405366e0
03-20 15:45:13.964: W/KeyCharacterMap(5540): Can't open keycharmap file
03-20 15:45:13.964: W/KeyCharacterMap(5540): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/synaptics-rmi-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='synaptics-rmi-touchscreen'
03-20 15:45:13.964: I/KeyCharacterMap(5540): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-20 15:45:14.304: D/WindowManagerImpl(5540): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[2]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405366e0
```

Payload is my message text. Any help would be appreciated.